# customize continue reading

Tags: css

This is the code of continue reading in function.php

```
<?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyten' ) ); ?>
```

It has a class which named **meta-nav** I tried to find the class and change it but I couldn't find that. Where is that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

the css class `.meta-nav` might or might not be referenced in style.css or any other stylesheet of the theme.

if your theme is ***Twenty Ten*** then the css class is ***not*** used in style.css - add it as a new style if you need.

Comment: where should I add it? if in style I already added but nothing changed. Where css class uses in this theme?

Comment: you could add it anywhere in style.css; just make sure to clear the browser cache.

Comment: nothing changed

Comment: this is turning into a question about formatting/css which is outside the scope of this forum; possibly ask at http://wordpress.org/support/ and provide a link to your site with a description of what you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider adding your own second class to the span such as: `<?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav MYCLASSNAME">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyten' ) ); ?>`all lowercase of course, then in your CSS just style it something like, 
`.myclassname {
display:inline;
color:#333;
font-weight:bold;
}`
Just as an example. That way you don't have to touch the original class and you can just add your own to it. I hope that helps!

Comment: this is gonna just change the arrow &rarr; it won't change the word